# Is it possible to over write _create function of jquery autocomplete plug in

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-autocomplete

All

Is it possible to over write _create function of autocomplete plug in ?

If so, What is the right approach ?

I want to over write create function because of the problems I faced:

**problems :**

**1.UP and DOWN arrow keys**

In case of up and down arrow keys,

autocomplete plugin is having event.preventDefault(); , Because of this it is preventing
  the caret movement inside the textarea even if the menu is not visible.

**2. Escape key**

In my case, If I press escape key while typing in text area I've to clear the text in the
  text area. But autocomplete plug in resets the value typed in the text area in case of
  escape key pressed.

SO,
  can you suggest me how  to over write the _create function of jquery autocomplete plugin?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

To overwrite the _create function:

```
$.ui.autocomplete.prototype._create = function () {
    // new create function
}
```

An alternative is to simply change the source code of [jquery.ui.autocomplete.js](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-ui/blob/master/ui/jquery.ui.autocomplete.js) and include the changed file.

Comment: I'm not authorized to change the jquery.ui.autocomplete.js file directly. Is there any other way of doing it? And what about the problems I mentioned , What's the best way to solve them ??

Answer (score 0):

Well, in my opinion, there is not much you can do without *dirty* coding.

There is a way to limit the alteration though. It is to unbind the original `keydown` event handler binded in the plugin and re-bind the event with your modified handler (based of course on the original one).

It's not very complicated, the key to do this is to get the plugin instance that is saved on the element as jquery-data with `$(this).data('autocomplete');`

Here's the code:

```
$('#myinput').autocomplete({ ... })
    .unbind("keydown.autocomplete")
    .bind("keydown.autocomplete", function(event) {

        // obtain the plugin instance
        var self = $(this).data('autocomplete');

        if (self.options.disabled || self.element.propAttr("readOnly")) {
            return;
        }

        suppressKeyPress = false;
        var keyCode = $.ui.keyCode;
        switch (event.keyCode) {
        case keyCode.PAGE_UP:
            self._move("previousPage", event);
            break;
        case keyCode.PAGE_DOWN:
            self._move("nextPage", event);
            break;
        case keyCode.UP:
            self._move("previous", event);

            // disable the prevent
            // event.preventDefault();

            break;
        case keyCode.DOWN:
            self._move("next", event);

            // disable the prevent
            // event.preventDefault();

            break;
        case keyCode.ENTER:
        case keyCode.NUMPAD_ENTER:
            // when menu is open and has focus
            if (self.menu.active) {
                // #6055 - Opera still allows the keypress to occur
                // which causes forms to submit
                suppressKeyPress = true;
                event.preventDefault();
            }
            //passthrough - ENTER and TAB both select the current element
        case keyCode.TAB:
            if (!self.menu.active) {
                return;
            }
            self.menu.select(event);
            break;
        case keyCode.ESCAPE:

            // clear the input value on ESC
            self.element.val('');

            self.close(event);
            break;
        default:
            // keypress is triggered before the input value is changed
            clearTimeout(self.searching);
            self.searching = setTimeout(function() {
                // only search if the value has changed
                if (self.term != self.element.val()) {
                    self.selectedItem = null;
                    self.search(null, event);
                }
            }, self.options.delay);
            break;
        }
    });
```

---

**Here's a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/didierg/Ma7B6/) to illustrate.**

Comment: Thank you for the useful Info. One more thing is when ever I add autocomplete to textarea, It is slow in IE how can I improve it's performance any suggestions from your side ?? Thanks in advance

Comment: Just like that I've got no idea. The plugin was not intended to be used with textareas in the first place. Maybe just because it is IE. When is it 'slow' (showing, getting the data...)?

Comment: If the menu is visible , If we press Up or Down arrow to focus previous or next item in the menu, The hover state is moving very slowly

Comment: Could be anything. Have you tried on a input element ? With/without the hack from the answer ? Do you have other code/binding on the menu ?

Comment: Could you please upvote and accept the answer if it responded to your question.

Comment: yes, I over written the render item function $("#txtArea").data( "autocomplete" )._renderItem = function( ul, item ){ // I'm appending html to the each item.                               return   $( "<li></li>" ).data( "item.autocomplete", item )
                   .append( $( "<a></a>" ).append(img).append(itm))
                   .attr( "title","custom").appendTo( ul );}           so I guess this may be the problem but it's fast in other browsers except IE